# How could I print out the nth letter of the alphabet in Python?

Tags: python

ASCII math doesn't seem to work in Python:

> > 'a' + 5
> >     DOESN'T WORK

How could I quickly print out the nth letter of the alphabet without having an array of letters?

My naive solution is this:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
print letters[5]
```

Comment: You could shorten your naive solution with `letters="ABCDEF...XYZ"`

Comment: Or if it absolutely *must* be a list, `letters=list("ABCDEF..etc.")` or `letters=list(string.uppercase)` (note that string.uppercase changes its name in Py3).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`chr` and `ord` convert characters from and to integers, respectively. So:

```
chr(ord('a') + 5)
```

is the letter `'f'`.

Comment: It is the 5th letter from `'a'`, obviously. And yes, I'm zero-indexing. What self-respecting programmer doesn't? ;)

Comment: And to do the reverse: ord(5) - ord('a')

Answer (score 38):

ASCII math aside, you don't have to type your letters table by hand.
The [string constants](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) in the `string module` provide what you were looking for.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase[5]
'F'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
chr(ord('a')+5)
```

<sup>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</sup>

Answer (score 3):

if u want to go really out of the way (probably not very good) you could create a new class CharMath:

```
class CharMath:
    def __init__(self,char):
        if len(char) > 1: raise IndexError("Not a single character provided")
        else: self.char = char
    def __add__(self,num):
        if type(num) == int or type(num) == float: return chr(ord(self.char) + num)
        raise TypeError("Number not provided")
```

The above can be used:

```
>>> CharMath("a") + 5
'f'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ord` function, like

```
print(ord('a')-5)
```

Edit: gah, I was too slow :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
print string.letters[n + is_upper*26]
```

For example:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> is_upper = False
>>> string.letters[n+is_upper*26]
'f'
>>> is_upper = True
>>> string.letters[n+is_upper*26]
'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like it short, try the lambda notation:

```
>>> A = lambda c: chr(ord('a')+c)
>>> A(5)
'f'
```