# What does ord(c) and chr(n) do and what does this code output and why? I do not understand the CODE BELOW mostly

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I need help understanding what the functions ord() and chr() do in ASCII code. I also have some code that I want to know why it outputs what it does.

I've been trying to decipher how this code works exactly. I'm not sure how and why it just outputs random letters...

```
message = ''
for letter in 'secret':
    number = ord(letter)
    newNumber = number + 1
    newLetter = chr(newNumber)
    message = message + newLetter
print(message)
```

I have no error messages because my teacher wrote it :D, lol. But, it outputs "tfdsfu" which is correct, but I don't know why.

Comment: Look up what `ord` (gets a asciis integer value) and `chr` (turns integer values back into charcters) do. As it sits the code is just grabbing the next ascii character (`a` becomes `b`). Btw in the future you should read the official documentation before asking a question you could have easily answered yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I print out the nth letter of the alphabet in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724473/how-could-i-print-out-the-nth-letter-of-the-alphabet-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ord()` gives you integer representation of a character. Take a look at an ASCII table to find out what they are. 'A' has an ASCII value of 65, 'B' has an ASCII value of 66, and so on.

`chr()` is the inverse. Given an integer value, it converts it into a character. `chr(65) == 'A'`.

If you take the ordinal value of `'A'`, you get 65. If you add 1 and convert it back, you get `chr(66)`, or `'B'`.

This also works with unicode characters (although that doesn't pertain to the code in your question).

Comment: To be complete, you should mention in Python 3+ the mapping between characters and integers is based on Unicode, not ASCII.